# Как сгенерировать случайные координаты в кольце которое образуется из двух кругов?

Tags: геометрия, lua

У меня есть два радиуса:

- Маленький = `100` (Центр `0, 0`)
- Большой = `150` (Центр `0, 0`)

Мне нужно найти случайную координату в кольце (Большой - Маленький)

Как это сделать?

Comment: Например, выбрать случайный угол, а потом случайное число от 100 до 150. Правда, это не совсер равномерное распределение, но вы же ничего об этом в условии не сказали?

Comment: Плюнуть в большой круг, проверить, не попал ли в малый, если нет - вернуть, если да - повторить...

Comment: Зря закрыли, вопрос не вполне тривиальный, хотя и не вполне качественно сформулирован.

Answer (score 1):

Сгенерировать случайный угол, равномерно распределенный по всему диапазону

```
Fi  = 2*PI * Random()
```

Сгенерировать случайное число, равномерно распределенное в диапазоне от квадрата радиуса внутреннего круга до квадрата радиуса внешнего

```
SquaredR  = r*r + Random()*(R*R - r*r)
```

Извлечь из последней величины квадратный корень

```
ra = Sqrt(SquaredR)
```

Получить координаты в кольце, они распределены однородно благодаря использованному преобразованию.

```
x, y = ra * Cos(Fi), ra * Sin(Fi)
```

Comment: @ДенисБас Если ответ помог, его можно принять как решение